LocalHost: 404 Not Found
I am following along with this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AClnCg_WCJk&t=303s
to create a login and signup page for my react js project and currently implementing the forget password functionality. However when I post forgot-password and try to fetch it when typing in the email, the console throws POST http://localhost:3001/forgot-password 404 (Not Found) @ handlesubmit
Client side port number is 3001 and the mongoDB is 3000, it works when logging in or signing up, just not the forgot password functionality. I have tried changing the port number to 3000 but it can't find the host still.
Backend: app.post("/forgot-password", async (req, res) => {
const { email } = req.body;
try {
  const oldUser = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!oldUser) {
    return res.json({ status: "User Not Exists!!" });
  }
  const secret = JWT_SECRET + oldUser.password;
  const token = jwt.sign({ email: oldUser.email, id: oldUser._id }, secret, {
    expiresIn: "5m",
  });
  const link = `http://localhost:3000/reset-password/${oldUser._id}/${token}`;
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "adarsh438tcsckandivali@gmail.com",
      pass: "rmdklolcsmswvyfw",
    },
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: "youremail@gmail.com",
    to: "thedebugarena@gmail.com",
    subject: "Password Reset",
    text: link,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
    }
  });
  console.log(link);
} catch (error) {}
});

var mailOptions = {
from: "youremail@gmail.com",
to: "thedebugarena@gmail.com",
subject: "Password Reset",
text: link,
};

Front-end: reset.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './reset.css'; 

export default class reset extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: "",
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {email} = this.state;
    console.log(email);
   //(throws the error - below )  
      fetch("/forgot-password", { 
        method: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
        }),
    })
        .then((res) => res.json()) 
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data, "userRegister");
            alert(data.status);
        });
   }

render() {
return (
    <form className='form-wrapper' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <h3>Forgot Password</h3>

        <div className='mb-3'>
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type='email' className='form-control' placeholder='Enter Email' onChange=    {(e) => this.setState({email: e.target.value})}
            />
        </div>

        <div className='d-grid'>
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </div>
        <p className='forgot-password text-right'>
            <a href='/signup'>Sign Up</a>    
        </p>     
    </form>
);
}
}

